# Spring Cloud Dataflow - Deploy Stream Without Starting

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

When deploying an application in PCF, it is possible to deploy the application without starting by running cf push --no-start.

In the same way, is it possible to deploy a Spring Cloud Dataflow stream without starting the underlying applications?

Answer (score 0):

The use-case description would be useful to understand why you'd like to deploy a stream and not start it. A stream is a continuous thing - it is meant to be running all the time.

If you're looking to address on-demand style use-cases, it'd be recommended to run them as Task pipelines instead. In fact, the tasks by default are pushed with `--no-start` [equivalent](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java#L110) and upon a launch trigger *(e.g., a schedule, manual launch. etc.,)*, it is actually started then.

Comment: We have availability zones A and B, but our consumer is currently only setup to consume from A.  We would like to deploy to both A and B and just start stream B when our consumer is ready (without having to worry about deploying it).

Comment: Thanks, @Awake. Please track [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry#204](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/issues/204) for progress and release timeline.